# EC2 - Java RMI using private ip

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, rmi

I have 3 ubuntu instances in amazon EC2. They are all under same subnet id.

Now when i use JAVA RMI among these hosts, if I use the private IP(172...), it does not work at all. If use the public ip (52...), it works as expected.

I need to explicitly mention this `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP` in the slave

[You can refer to this question [JMeter - docker - java.net.connectexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698220/jmeter-docker-java-net-connectexception) for the java application which uses RMI ]

I am able to telnet (telnet 172... 1099) using the private ip, it is able to connect to the other hosts.

Why should i pass public ip? Or How it can be done using private ip?

---

**Slaves security settings:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass the public IP, and in fact that shouldn't even work unless you have port 1099 open to the internet in your security group(s). This behavior isn't making sense. Can you provide the settings for all the relevant security groups?

Comment: @MarkB, Question is updated. all the ports are open.

Comment: @EJP because using the public IP results in the request being routed over the internet, while using the private IP keeps the traffic local to the VPC. Obviously using the private IP will be more secure, as well as faster.

Comment: @KitKarson I can't think of any reason this wouldn't work when using the private IP. Do you have any non-standard routes in your VPC route table? Can you post the exact error message you get when attempting to use the private IPs?

Comment: @MarkB, No issues. thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @MarkB, I get connection timeout error !! I triple checked i give the correct ip. public ip works great! I am able to telnet with private ip... so it sounds really strange.